# SQL Server does not support the equivalent of ORACLE's %TYPE and %ROWTYPE

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I writing a cursor to select data from a table into variables.

Using oracle I could simply use a single declare statement that in effect creates a variable for every column with a data type that matches the type of the underlying table (as it is currently defined at runtime)..

In SQL server it would seem you have to manually declare a variable for every column.

Am I right.  Does anyone have any thoughts?

I think this is a massive reason to dislike SQL Server when compared to oracle.

I am so disappointed that SS doesn't have %TYPE and %ROWTYPE.  These save hours of work when initially writing code and in the event that the type of a column needs to change, it saves having to go back and re-work all the code.

In Oracle I used to write something like:

DECLARE @MyRowVar AS  ATable%ROWTYPE;

In SQL Server, I just had to write this this:

```
DECLARE @External_ID                AS BIGINT = NULL;
DECLARE @PlatformID                 AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @ActorIDOfReseller          AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @ActorIDOfClient            AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @ActorIDOfExtension         AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @CallType                   AS NCHAR (10) = NULL;
DECLARE @CallInitiatedDate          AS DATE = NULL;
DECLARE @CallInitiatedTimeHH24MI    AS TIME (0) = NULL;
DECLARE @TimePeriodID               AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @CallAnswered               AS DATETIME = NULL;
DECLARE @CallAnsweredYN             AS BIT = NULL;
DECLARE @CallDispositionID          AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @CountryID                  AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @CallPrefixID               AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @FromNumber                 AS VARCHAR (32) = NULL;
DECLARE @ToNumber                   AS VARCHAR (80) = NULL;
DECLARE @CallDuration               AS INT = NULL;
DECLARE @CallCostToExtension        AS DECIMAL (10, 6) = NULL;
DECLARE @CallCostToClient           AS DECIMAL (10, 6) = NULL;
DECLARE @CallCostToReseller         AS DECIMAL (10, 6) = NULL;
DECLARE @CallCostToAdmin            AS DECIMAL (10, 6) = NULL;
DECLARE @Flow                       AS VARCHAR (3) = NULL;
DECLARE @CallStart                  AS DATETIME = NULL;
DECLARE @MoneyUnit                  AS VARCHAR (32) = NULL;
DECLARE @Prefix                     AS VARCHAR (32) = NULL;
DECLARE @External_CallID            AS VARCHAR (255) = NULL;
```

This is making me very sad and is a waste of my life.

I tagged this as Oracle, as I'm sure oracle developers will want to know how lucky they are to work with this professional tool.

Harvey

---

Continued.

From the comment below it appears there is an easier way!  Thanks very much for the input.  I was ranting as I got a bit knarked....sorry.

Here's some more context:

1. I have a csv file, with unreliable data in each column.
2. I BULK LOAD this csv file into tableA which has all columns declared as VARCHAR(100).   (The file loads even if the data type of values aren't what was expected in the column)
3. I used a single statement to transfer the data from tableA into tableB.
   TableB has the same columns as tableA, but tableB columns have a variety of datatypes - which are the expected datatypes that the csv data should have.

(TableB also has a few other columns not populated form the file, eg an IDENTITY column, etc..).

The statement is something like:

INSERT INTO tableB 
(column list) 
SELECT 
( {column list for select} ) 
FROM tableB;

Each column in the {column list for select} above, has is wrapped with the TRY_CAST function to convert it to the same data type as the destination table or NULL.

4. The above step 3 worked OK, but I had no way of identifying the invalid rows.
   So I decided to try to use a cursor and use the same select statement as in step 3 but without the TRY_CAST wrapping each column.  I used a TRY/CATCH around the whole INSERT statement that operated on each row of the select statement to log the invalid rows when the INSERT failed.
5. I've now written Step 4 but boy I wish I'd posted a "how do I do this" question here first.  My code looks really rubbish and I've posted it below.

As you can probably tell, I've not been using SQL Server long and I'm pretty rusty at using big databases..

Any more input you can give is very welcome.  I'll re-write this tomorrow!

I like Jermey's suggestion of creating a temp table using teh SQL below, but I've not completely got my head around this yet!

Select *
INTO #tmp
From mytable
Where 1 = 0;

Any way, here it is.

(I've run this now and it took 30 seconds to process 254,000 rows, - only one of which was a failure - but this time is acceptable.)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Call_Process_FromXoomTalk_UsingCursor]
      @PlatformId int 
    , @StartOfMonthDate as Date = NULL
    , @EndOfMonthDate   as Date = NULL
    , @LimitImportToRowsWithThisCallType nVarchar(max) = NULL
    , @LimitImportToRowsWithThisFlow nVarchar(max)  = NULL
    , @Raise1Print2Both3 as tinyint  = 3
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @msg as nVarchar(max);
    DECLARE @RowCount as int = 0;
    DECLARE @FETCHSTATUS as int = 0;
    DECLARE @CountOfRowFailures AS INT = 0;
    DECLARE @CountOfRowSuccesses AS INT = 0;

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- The order any type of the variables declared below
    -- MUST match the order of the columns of the CURSOR SELECT statement below and
    -- the data type of the underlying columns of the table "Call".
    --
    -- CALL TABLE COLUMNS:
    --
    DECLARE @External_ID                AS BIGINT = NULL;
    DECLARE @PlatformID2                AS INT = NULL;
    DECLARE @ActorIDOfReseller          AS INT = NULL;
    DECLARE @ActorIDOfClient            AS INT = NULL;
    DECLARE @ActorIDOfExtension         AS INT = NULL;

    DECLARE @CallType                   AS NCHAR (10) = NULL;

    DECLARE @CallInitiatedDate          AS DATE = NULL;
    DECLARE @CallInitiatedTimeHH24MI    AS TIME (0) = NULL;
    DECLARE @TimePeriodID               AS INT = NULL;

    DECLARE @CallAnswered               AS DATETIME = NULL;
    DECLARE @CallAnsweredYN             AS BIT = NULL;

    DECLARE @CallDispositionID          AS INT = NULL;

    DECLARE @CountryID                  AS INT = NULL;
    DECLARE @CallPrefixID               AS INT = NULL;

    DECLARE @FromNumber                 AS VARCHAR (32) = NULL;
    DECLARE @ToNumber                   AS VARCHAR (80) = NULL;
    DECLARE @CallDuration               AS INT = NULL;

    DECLARE @CallCostToExtension        AS DECIMAL (10, 6) = NULL;
    DECLARE @CallCostToClient           AS DECIMAL (10, 6) = NULL;
    DECLARE @CallCostToReseller         AS DECIMAL (10, 6) = NULL;
    DECLARE @CallCostToAdmin            AS DECIMAL (10, 6) = NULL;

    DECLARE @Flow                       AS VARCHAR (3) = NULL;
    DECLARE @CallStart                  AS DATETIME = NULL;

    DECLARE @MoneyUnit                  AS VARCHAR (32) = NULL;
    DECLARE @Prefix                     AS VARCHAR (32) = NULL;
    DECLARE @External_CallID            AS VARCHAR (255) = NULL;

    -- END OF CALL TABLE COLUMNS:
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- SETTINGS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            PRINT ' ';
            PRINT '===================================================================================';
            EXEC [PrintSystemTime]  'Starting: [Call_Process_FromXoomTalk_UsingCursor]';
            PRINT '===================================================================================';


            --
            -- It is assumed that the file loaded into the CallData table
            -- only contains calls made in the year and month provided to this procedure
            --

            --
            -- Move rows from the staging table [CallDATA] into the main table
            -- [Call].  Some simple looks and modifications are made 
            --

            -----------------------------------------------------------------
            -- Define the cursor
            -- WARNING - For simplicity keep column order in step with the 
            --           variable declarations, select and insert  use!
            --

            DECLARE curNewData CURSOR FAST_FORWARD 
            FOR
            SELECT Table1.* 
            FROM 
            ( SELECT 
                    -- ID is identity field
                    [id] AS  [ExternalID]
                    ,   @PlatformId AS [PlatformID]

                    ,   ( SELECT SubQry.[ID]
                            FROM [dbo].[Actor] AS SubQry
                            WHERE SubQry.[ExternalID] = [NewData].client_reseller_id 
                        ) AS Actor_ResellerID

                    ,   ( SELECT SubQry.[ID]
                            FROM [dbo].[Actor] AS SubQry
                            WHERE SubQry.[ExternalID] = NewData.client_client_id 
                        ) AS Actor_ClientID

                    ,   ( SELECT SubQry.[ID]
                            FROM [dbo].[Actor] AS SubQry
                            WHERE SubQry.[ExternalID] = NewData.client_extension_id 
                        ) AS Actor_ExtensionID

                    -- This code prevent invalid values being loaded
                    -- that would be rejected byt eh foreigh key  
                    , CASE [calltype] 
                        WHEN 'out'    THEN 'out' 
                        WHEN 'in'     THEN 'in'
                        WHEN 'local'  THEN 'local'
                        WHEN 'elocal' THEN 'elocal'
                        ELSE NULL
                    END AS [calltype]

                    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    --
                    -- Initiated date/time is split to produce derrived columns
                    --
                    -- , [initiated] as [initiated]  -- Useful for testing

                    -- NOTE that CAST will convert 0000-00-00 00:00:00  to be NULL
                    , TRY_CAST([initiated] AS DATE) AS [CallInitiatedDate]

                    , TRY_CAST([initiated] AS TIME(0)) AS  [CallInitiatedTimeHH24MI]

                    ,   ( SELECT isnull(GroupWithTHISID,[ID]) as ID
                            FROM [dbo].[DimTimePeriod] AS SubQry
                            WHERE SubQry.[ActorID]        = NewData.[client_client_id]
                            AND TRY_CAST([initiated] AS TIME(0)) >= SubQry.[StartTimeHH24MI] 
                            AND TRY_CAST([initiated] AS TIME(0)) <  SubQry.[EndTimeHH24MI]   
                        ) AS  [TimePeriodID]

    -- What format are their dates! Do they have nano secs              
                    , TRY_CAST([answer] as datetime2) AS  [CallAnswered]
                    , iif([answer] is null,0,1) AS  [CallAnsweredYN]
                    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    , ( SELECT X.[ID]
                        FROM [dbo].[DimCallDisposition] AS X
                        WHERE X.[Disposition] = NewData.[disposion]
                        ) AS  [CallDispositionID]

                    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    --
                    -- Population of Country and Area require significant processing that is done later
                    -- 
                    , NULL AS  [CountryID]
                    , NULL AS  [AreaID]

                    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    -- Useful for testing
                    -- , [extension_number] AS  [FromClientAndNumber]
                    , RIGHT([extension_number],LEN([extension_number])-CHARINDEX('*',[extension_number],1)) AS  [FromNumber]

                    ,   CASE LEFT([partyid],2)
                            WHEN '00' THEN 
                                -- Replace 00 with a + ie for all international numbers
                                '+' + SUBSTRING([partyid],3,9999)
                            ELSE [partyid] 
                        END AS  [ToNumber]

                    , [duration] AS  [CallDuration_SECS]

                    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    -- COST columns
                    --
                    -- NOTE: Some data in the cost fields in the file from the xoomtalk platform 
                    --       was in scientific notation format
                    --       eg 4.2e-05    4.2e-05    7.2e-05    6.2e-05    8.3e-05  8.3e-05
                    --       Note that these were all very small values!

                    ,   CASE 
                            WHEN [costext] like '%E-%' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(TRY_CAST(TRY_CAST([costext] AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(10,6))))
                            WHEN [costext] like '%E+%' THEN NULL
                            ELSE TRY_CAST([costext] AS DECIMAL(10,6))
                        END AS  [CallCostToExtension]


                    ,   CASE 
                            WHEN NewData.[costcl] like '%E-%' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(TRY_CAST(TRY_CAST([costcl] AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(10,6))))
                            WHEN [costcl] like '%E+%' THEN NULL
                            ELSE TRY_CAST([costcl] AS DECIMAL(10,6))
                        END AS  [CallCostToClient]

                    ,   CASE 
                            WHEN NewData.[costres] like '%E-%' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(TRY_CAST(TRY_CAST([costres] AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(10,6))))
                            WHEN [costres] like '%E+%' THEN NULL
                            ELSE TRY_CAST([costres] AS DECIMAL(10,6))
                        END AS  [CallCostToReseller]

                    ,   CASE 
                            WHEN NewData.[costadmin] like '%E-%' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(TRY_CAST(TRY_CAST([costadmin] AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(10,6))))
                            WHEN [costadmin] like '%E+%' THEN NULL
                            ELSE TRY_CAST([costadmin] AS DECIMAL(10,6))
                        END AS  [CallCostToAdmin]

                    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                    , [flow]       AS Flow 
                    , [start]      AS [CallStart]

                    , [moneyunit]  AS [moneyunit]
                    , [prefix]     AS [prefix]
                    , [callid]     AS [External_CallID]

                    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                FROM [dbo].[CallDATA] AS NewData

                WHERE ( (@LimitImportToRowsWithThisCallType IS NULL)
                        OR NewData.[calltype] = @LimitImportToRowsWithThisCallType
                    )
                AND ( (@LimitImportToRowsWithThisFlow IS NULL)
                        OR NewData.[flow] = @LimitImportToRowsWithThisFlow
                    )
                AND TRY_CAST([initiated] as datetime2) >= @StartOfMonthDate
                AND TRY_CAST([initiated] as datetime2) <= @EndOfMonthDate

            ) as Table1

            ORDER BY  [calltype]
                    , [flow]
                    , [CallInitiatedDate]
                    , [CallInitiatedTimeHH24MI]
                    , [CallDuration_SECS]
            ;




            -----------------------------------------------------------------
            -- Open and use the cursor
            --

            PRINT '------------------------------------------------------------------';
            PRINT 'ABOUT TO LIST the external_ID of any ROWS that failed to insert';

            OPEN curNewData;

            SET @FETCHSTATUS = 0;
            SET @CountOfRowFailures = 0;
            SET @CountOfRowSuccesses = 0;

            WHILE @FETCHSTATUS = 0
            BEGIN

                FETCH NEXT FROM curNewData
                    INTO
                          @External_ID
                        , @PlatformID2
                        , @ActorIDOfReseller
                        , @ActorIDOfClient
                        , @ActorIDOfExtension

                        , @CallType

                        , @CallInitiatedDate
                        , @CallInitiatedTimeHH24MI
                        , @TimePeriodID

                        , @CallAnswered
                        , @CallAnsweredYN

                        , @CallDispositionID

                        , @CountryID
                        , @CallPrefixID

                        , @FromNumber
                        , @ToNumber
                        , @CallDuration

                        , @CallCostToExtension
                        , @CallCostToClient
                        , @CallCostToReseller
                        , @CallCostToAdmin

                        , @Flow
                        , @CallStart

                        , @MoneyUnit
                        , @Prefix
                        , @External_CallID
                ;

                BEGIN TRY

                    INSERT INTO dbo.Call 
                        (
                          [External_ID]
                        , [PlatformID]
                        , [ActorID-OfReseller]
                        , [ActorID-OfClient]
                        , [ActorID-OfExtension]


                        , [CallType]

                        , [CallInitiatedDate]
                        , [CallInitiatedTimeHH24MI]
                        , [TimePeriodID]

                        , [CallAnswered]
                        , [CallAnsweredYN]

                        , [CallDispositionID]

                        , [CountryID]
                        , CallPrefixID

                        , [FromNumber]
                        , [ToNumber]
                        , [CallDuration]

                        , [CallCostToExtension]
                        , [CallCostToClient]
                        , [CallCostToReseller]
                        , [CallCostToAdmin]

                        , [Flow]
                        , [CallStart]

                        , [MoneyUnit]
                        , [Prefix]                 
                        , [External_CallID]

                        )

                    VALUES

                        ( @External_ID
                        , @PlatformID2
                        , @ActorIDOfReseller
                        , @ActorIDOfClient
                        , @ActorIDOfExtension

                        , @CallType

                        , @CallInitiatedDate
                        , @CallInitiatedTimeHH24MI
                        , @TimePeriodID

                        , @CallAnswered
                        , @CallAnsweredYN

                        , @CallDispositionID

                        , @CountryID
                        , @CallPrefixID

                        , @FromNumber
                        , @ToNumber
                        , @CallDuration

                        , @CallCostToExtension
                        , @CallCostToClient
                        , @CallCostToReseller
                        , @CallCostToAdmin

                        , @Flow
                        , @CallStart

                        , @MoneyUnit
                        , @Prefix
                        , @External_CallID
                        )
                    ;

                    SET @CountOfRowSuccesses = @CountOfRowSuccesses + 1;

                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                    -- Ignore error
                    PRINT CONCAT(@External_ID, '|', ERROR_NUMBER(), '|', ERROR_MESSAGE());
                    SET @CountOfRowFailures = @CountOfRowFailures + 1;

                END CATCH;


                SET @FETCHSTATUS = @@FETCH_STATUS;

            END;

            CLOSE curNewData;
            DEALLOCATE curNewData;

            PRINT '------------------------------------------------------------------';
            PRINT CONCAT('Count Of Row Failures =', @CountOfRowFailures)
            PRINT CONCAT('Count Of Row Successes=', @CountOfRowSuccesses)
            PRINT '------------------------------------------------------------------';



        COMMIT;
        PRINT '################################ ';
        PRINT 'COMMIT DONE';
        PRINT '################################ ';


        EXEC [PrintSystemTime] 'Ending: [Call_Process_FromXoomTalk_UsingCursor]';
        PRINT '=========================================================================';

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

            IF @Raise1Print2Both3 = 2 OR @Raise1Print2Both3 = 3
                EXEC [dbo].[ErrPrintErrorDetails] 
                      @CalledFromProcedure= '[dbo].[Call_Process_FromXoomTalk_UsingCursor]'
                    , @ExplainitoryErrorTextForUser  = NULL
                    , @AddDottedLine = 1;

        EXEC [PrintSystemTime] 'Ending with Error: [Call_Process_FromXoomTalk_UsingCursor]' ;
        PRINT '=========================================================================';

        ROLLBACK;
        PRINT '################################ ';
        PRINT 'ROLLBACK DONE';
        PRINT '################################ ';

        IF @Raise1Print2Both3 = 1 OR @Raise1Print2Both3 = 3
            THROW;

    END CATCH;

END
```

Comment: As written, this seems like more of a rant than a question.  It's much less common (for a variety of reasons) to use cursors in SQL Server than it is in Oracle.  Most things that I'd use a cursor and a `%ROWTYPE` for in Oracle I'd use a temp table in SQL Server.  Not knowing exactly what problem you're trying to solve, though, it's hard to know whether that is a better solution to your problem.

Comment: Almost 100% certain there is a way to do what you want to do in an easy way in SQL Server.  since we don't know what you are trying to do there is no way to help you.

Comment: Agreed, if your first thought is to create a cursor in SQL Server, you need to re-evaluate your solution. 99% of the time the problem can be solved using set based logic, which SQL Server much prefers over row by row processing.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comments.  They were useful.  Sorry about the rant, I was getting frustrated with myself not being fluent in this anymore.  I hope you find the additional text I have added gives you the info you need to make some further suggestions.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately sometimes you have to change your tactics when you move from Oracle to SQL Server.

Back to your case, if you are processing a large data set and you want to catch the bad rows, try give your raw imported table an unique id column, start from the smallest id, copy limited rows to the new table (use cast, not try_cast) each time. When you see an error, the insert will fail and you can reduce the number of insert rows until you reach the bad row. Move it to a "bad row" and continue try other data. After all rows copied, you have one table for the good rows and one for the bad rows. Then deal with the bad ones.

It may not be the fast solution but you don't have to spend too many times perfecting your script and basically it's a one-pass solution.

Here is the concept :

```
 Alter table imported_table add lid int identity(1,1) not null primary key;

 select top 1 into bad_rows from imported_table ; 
 truncate table bad_rows;
```

Then run this code:

```
declare @last_id int, @r int,@c int;
select @last_id= 0; @r = 100;
while @last_id >=0 begin
  begin try
  insert into new_table (.....)
  select top(@r) .... from imported_table where lid>@last_id order by lid;
  select @c=@@rowcount;
  if @c<1 select @last_id=-1 --- end of loop
  else select @last_id=@last_id + @c;
  select @r = 100;
  end try
  begin catch
  if @r <2 begin
      insert into bad_rows(...) 
      select top(@r)... from imported_table 
      where lid>@last_id order by lid;
      select @lid=@lid+1;
  end 
  else select @r=@r / 2;
  end catch;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I understand your code and I can see that it would work.  However using this technique you will still need to declare one variable for every field of the destination table.In Oracle I vaguely remember simply doing  
  
DECLARE MyRowVaraible AS atab%ROWTYPE;  
  
SELECT atab.* FROM atab INTO MyRowVaraible  
  
INSERT MyRowVaraible   INTO  tabB  
  
Also, I'm not sold on this technique.   
Say 10% of the csv being loaded has invalid data rows, the code I wrote would result in 10% failed inserts.   Your code would result in considerably more, probably around 10 times as many.

Comment: My code uses no local variables for columns, which is the main point.  You can change the batch size to 1, to eliminate repeat tries on invalid rows, but not necessarily speed up transferring.

Comment: Brilliant.  I get it now....  That is very handy.  I'll try re-writing my code to use this technique and lot you know how I get on.  You know they say it takes a genius to spot a genius... well sorry I'm clearly not one!

Comment: I am massively relieved that there is this rather nice workaround... but I notice that requests have been made to add %ROWTYPE  and %TYPE as these would help in other situations - i think - like parameter data types etc...

Comment: PS.  Massive thanks tim3880.  You've clearly read all my post and that's great!

Answer (score 0):

Others have stated that using temp tables is a possibility.

If you want to easily create a temp table with the same data types as your source, you can use Select INTO syntax such as

```
Select *
INTO #tmp
From mytable
Where 1 = 0
```

You can use this with only select columns, joins, etc to create a temporary working space without having to declare variables and data types